# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

Tags: javascript, php, html, json

Hi (and sorry as I am new to using this site), I am getting the error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

in the php code below:

```
while ($vrstica = mysqli_fetch_array($rezultat)) {
    echo  '<link rel="shortcut icon" href="#" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    let podatki = [];
    podatki = <?php echo json_encode($vrstica); ?>; 

      google.charts.load("current", {"packages":["corechart"]});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);


        function drawChart(cas, hitrost) {

            let pomTabela = [["Datum", "Hitrost [m/s]"]];
            for(let i=0; i<podatki.length; i+=2){ 
                pomTabela.push([podatki[i],podatki[i+1]]);}

       var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(pomTabela);


        var options = {
          title: "Povprecna hitrost vetra - zadnjih 7 dni",
          legend: { position: "bottom" }
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById("curve_chart"));

        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>';
}
```

Now it seems a part of that code, bellow echo does not wish to be displayed here but its only some script brackets.
**Also the error is connected with the line (which is now also not fully displayed...):**
podatki = ;

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line would be echoed literally, resulting in a syntax error:

```
podatki = <?php echo json_encode($vrstica); ?>;
```

Try something alike this:

```
podatki = '.json_encode($vrstica).';
```

The first one `'` ends the literal string, then comes the PHP execution result and the second one `'` continues with the literal string (the opening and closing `'` just happen to be in other lines).